# Find $x$ and $y$ - Why is there no answer?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find $x$ and $y$ from the following equations:

\begin{eqnarray*}
7x-3y &=& 8 \\
14x-6y &=& 21
\end{eqnarray*}

I my book it says there's "no answer". Can someone explain to me - why?

Thanks

Comment: Multiply the first equation by 2, and you'll see why.

Comment: Please improve the question by includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: An instructive exercise would be to put these two equations in point-slope or slope-intercept form and graph them on graph paper. That might give you a little insight into why the equations can't both be satisfied.

Comment: Because this amounts to $2\cdot8=21$ !

Comment: @Sahar Avr You can draw graphs and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multilpyng the first e quation by $-2$ and summing the two equations you find: $0=5$ that is impossible.

In other words: any couple $x,y$ that satisfies the first equation, cannot satisfies the second.

Answer (score 1):

Say we assume that $x$ and $y$ satisfy the first equation. Then $7x -3y =8$ so if we multiply by 2 we get $14x -6y =16$ which contradicts the second equation.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that both equations are true (for the moment). Using the first equation, we find $x=(8+3y)/7$. Take this solution, and plug it in to the second equation. The second equation becomes $2(8+3y)-6y=21$. The terms with y cancel, and we are left with 16=21 which is obviously wrong. But we didn't make a math error. In this scenario either: a.) one of the two equations we started with must be incorrect (which isn't the case since it was given at the start or b.) no set of {x=..., y=...} will solve the two equations simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your two equations in $y=mx+b$ form. You will see that both of there slopes or "$m$" values are the same. Two lines with the same slope are guaranteed parallel if they are not the same lines. Therefore because parallel lines never intersect, there were will not be a point $(x,y)$ that satisfies both equations. The point $(x,y)$ is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, multiplying the first equation gives $14x - 6y = 16$, it should not be 21.

Secondly, if you can, please check whether $(8,21)'$ belongs to the column space of the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}7 & -3\\ 14 & -6\end{pmatrix}$ or not. I think it must not belong to the column space of $A$, which means that the system is not consistent. Hence it has no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Double both sides of the first equation and you get
\begin{eqnarray*}
14x-6y &=& 16 \\
14x-6y &=& 21
\end{eqnarray*}

Both lines have a slope of $\frac{14}{6} = \frac 73$, so they are parallel to each other. Their y-intercepts are $-\frac{16}{6} = -\frac 83$ and $-\frac{21}{6} = -\frac 72.$ since they are parallel and have different y-intercepts, they never intersect.

Or, much more simply, this implies that $16 = 21$.

So there is no solution.